# check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1 how to fix

Tags: mysql, node.js, discord.js

I am writing a discord bot and I'm trying to get MySQL so I can keep my data about players. when I was trying to connect MySQL to discord.js, and node.js, it said:

ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

And I don't know what this means so if anyone knows how to fix this thankyou.

here is my code:

```
    const Discord = require('discord.js');
const mysql = require('mysql');

const client = new Discord.Client();
const prefix = "p ";

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('pog is online! Pogchamp')
    
})


var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "127.0.0.1",
  socketPath: "/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock",
  user: "root",
  password: "1234",
  database: "PogBot"
});
con.connect(function(err) {
    if (err)
    {
        console.log("ERROR: " + err.message);
        return;
    }
    console.log("Connected!");
});


/*shop*/
const shop = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#00FF00')
    .setTitle('Shop')
    .setDescription('Pog Shop')
    .addFields(
        { name: '\u200B', value: '\u200B' },
        { name: 'How to buy', value: 'use "pogs buy (itemName)"to buy an item' },
        { name: 'Laptop :computer:',         value: '1000 Coins', inline: true },
        { name: 'Phone :mobile_phone:',            value: '400 Coins', inline: true },
        { name: 'Mouse :mouse_three_button:',    value: '100 Coins', inline: true },
    )

client.on('message', message =>{
    if(message.author.bot)
        return;
    if(message.content.startsWith(prefix + "id"))
        message.author.send('your id: ' + message.author.id);
    
    if(message.content.startsWith(prefix + 'me')){
        sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = " + message.author.id;
        con.query(sql, function (err, result)
        {
            try
            {
                if (err) 
                    throw new exception(err.message);

                if (result.length > 1)
                    throw new exception("select user_id=" + message.author.id + " got (result.length) records");
                
                if (result.length == 0)
                {
                    console.log("Not user");
                    return;
                }
                
                message.channel.send("Tag: " + result[0].tag + "\nCoins: " + result[0].pog_coins);
            }
            catch( exception )
            {
                
                // WRITE TO FILE -> ... exception.message
                console.log("Something went wrong. Error #" + exception.line);
            }
        });
    }
    if(message.content.startsWith(prefix + "create")){
        
        sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = " + message.author.id;
        con.query(sql, function (err, result)
        {
            if (err) 
                console.log(err.message);

            if (result.length > 1)
            {
                message.channel.send("Account already created:");                    
                message.channel.send("Tag: " + result[0].tag + "\nCoins: " + result[0].pog_coins);
                return;
            }
            sql = "INSERT INTO users(user_id, tag, pog_coins)VALUES(" + message.author.id + ", " + message.author.tag + ", 0)";        
            con.query(sql, function (err        , result)
            {   
                if (err) 
                console.log(err.message);
                
                message.channel.send("Account Created!");   
            });
        });
    }
    if(message.content.startsWith(prefix + "shop"))
        message.channel.send(shop);
        
    /*if(message.content.startsWith('pog'))
        message.channel.send('champ')
    if(message.content.startsWith('champ'))
        message.channel.send('pog')*/
})
```

Comment: Probably, your `message.author.tag` has non-alphanumeric characters in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would help to know the actual query, that should have been part of the error message.

I assume that the problem is with

```
sql = "INSERT INTO users(user_id, tag, pog_coins)VALUES(" + message.author.id + ", " + message.author.tag + ", 0)";
```

and especially with:

```
    + message.author.tag +
```

I assume that the tag is text, not a number, so it needs to be but into quotes, e.g.

```
+ ", '" + message.author.tag + "', 0)"
     ^                          ^
```

But then the very next thing that can happen now is SQL injection, so you should look into using prepared statements for this, instead of constructing query strings by just using string concatenation.

Comment: omg, thank you soo much, you re the best!